# "This question body does not meet our quality standards."

Tags: support, question-quality

I've been trying to ask the following question:

> Title: Le sens de « qu' » dans « qu'à l'oral »
>
> Body: Je voudrais savoir le sens de « qu' » dans « qu'à l'oral ».

But each time this keeps popping up:

> This question body does not meet our quality standards. Please make
>   sure that it completely describes your problem - including what you
>   have already tried - and is written using proper grammar.

Is this a technical problem? Why can't I ask this question?

---

J'ai essayé de poser une question, mais la question a été refusée avec le message suivant :

> This question body does not meet our quality standards. Please make
>   sure that it completely describes your problem - including what you
>   have already tried - and is written using proper grammar.

Qu'est-ce que cela signifie ? Comment y remédier ?

Answer (score 6):

This is an automated filter that rejects low-quality questions. Exactly what is considered low-quality isn't public, to avoid people gaming it.

One of the things the filter picks up is the length of the question. Try asking a longer question. The filter would be right to consider your question too short: at least add a complete sentence. (*Que* can have many meanings, and it's impossible to tell what is meant without context.)

The filter also gives weight to some clues that are related to proper English grammar. This part should be turned off on sites such as this one where questions might not be in English at all. I'll check with the Stack Exchange staff that the grammar filter hasn't been turned on by mistake.

---

Il y a un filtre qui rejette les questions de mauvaise qualité. Les critères de ce filtre ne sont pas publics afin d'éviter les abus.

Un des critères est que la question ne doit pas être trop courte. Essayez avec une question plus longue. En l'occurrence le filtre aurait raison de se plaindre de la longueur de la question : « que » est un mot qui a beaucoup de sens, il faut plus de contexte pour savoir lequel est le bon. Ajoute une phrase complète dans la question.

Le filtre tient aussi compte de critères liés à la grammaire anglaise. Cet aspect devrait normalement être désactivé sur les sites comme celui-ci où une question peut très bien ne pas comporter un mot d'anglais. Je vais vérifier avec le personnel de Stack Exchange que cette partie du filtre n'a pas été activée par erreur.

Comment: Thanks. By the way: why do comments such as this one have to have a word count? I find this pretty stupid as it forces the user to add up letters, rather than words, just for the sake of adding them up. The same goes with edits, too.

Comment: @indoxica For comments, it's to avoid comments like "Thanks", "OK", "+1", that are considered more noisy than useful. To express you agreement with an answer, an upvote (or accepting the answer, if you were the OP) is the best way. As for edits, it's to avoid multiple, trivial edits.

Comment: Les imperatifs, *essayez* et *ajoute* c'est pas cohérent. *Beaucoup de sens* c'est mochement ambigu. Les phrases courtes c'est penible.